# Child of array element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a div with class cover_container and img inside it. The code used to get img height and apply it to its parent div. Here's what I did.

```
$('.cover_container').height($(".cover_container img").height());
```

Easy stuff. However, now I have multiple cover_containers on one page and I started to struggle. Here's what I did:

```
for($a = 0; $a < $('.cover_container').length; $a++) {
  $currentcovercontainer = $('.cover_container')[$a];
  $currentcovercontainer.height($currentcovercontainer.children('img')[0].height());
}
```

This, however, gives me the following error:

```
[21:33:57.440] TypeError: $currentcovercontainer.children is not a function
```

I've also tried ideas like jQuery($currentcovercontainer).find('img')[0].height() or $currentcovercontainer.height($('> img').height() however with no success.

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.each` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to execute a function 1 by 1

```
$('.cover_container').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.height($this.find("img").height());
});
```

[**See this example on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KJ8Vx/)

Answer (score 2):

I'll write this in [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) - you can either keep it as is or convert it to jQuery if you must:

```
var qsa = document.querySelectorAll(".cover_container"),
    l = qsa.length, i;
// note: querySelectorAll is more widely supported than getElementsByClassName
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    qsa[i].style.height = qsa[i].querySelector("img").height+"px";
}
```

It can be made simpler if your HTML is regular, such as `<div class="cover_container"><img src="..." /></div>`, because then you can use `qsa[i].children[0].height`

Answer (score 1):

`$('.cover_container')[$a]` gives you a DOM Element, not a jQuery object;

```
for(var $a = 0; $a < $('.cover_container').length; $a++) {
  var $currentcovercontainer = $($('.cover_container')[$a]);
  $currentcovercontainer.height($($currentcovercontainer.children('img')[0]).height());
}
```

... although [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) works like `[]`, but returns a jQuery object for you;

```
for(var $a = 0; $a < $('.cover_container').length; $a++) {
  var $currentcovercontainer = $('.cover_container').get($a);
  $currentcovercontainer.height($currentcovercontainer.children('img').height());
}
```

Although this could be more jQuery-esque using `each`;

```
$('.cover_container').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.height($this.children('img').height());
});
```

Also note that the `$a` syntax is usually used to denote a jQuery object; `$a` will be a number, not a jQuery object. Don't forget to declare your variables using `var` as well :).